# Ошибка времени выполнения: Индекс находился вне границ массива

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

PascalABC.NET как исправить ошибку?

```
    uses Arrays;
var 
  a: array of integer;
  N: integer;
  i1,i2:integer;
begin
  N := 50;
  a := CreateRandomIntegerArray(50);
  for var i:=1 to N do begin
    if a[i]>0 then
    i1+=1;
    if a[i]<0 then
    i2+=1;
   end;
write(i1);
write(i2);
end.
```

Answer (score 4):

Динамические массивы нумеруются с нуля. Цикл   `for var i:=1 to N do begin` должен выглядеть хотя бы так   `for var i:=0 to N-1 do begin`

А вообще стоит оперировать такими функциями работы с массивами, как `length`, `High` и т.п.